# How to draw polygons in leaflet using x and y coordinates instead of lat lng?

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, geojson

I am currently working with leaflet. I was able to draw the polygons with geojson using lat,lng with below code snippet:

```
var geolayer=L.geoJson(geodata);
```

But above code uses the latlng for drawing the polygons. Now is there any way possible to draw the polygon using x and y coordinate(eg:1,1)?

Comment: By 'x,y' Do you mean pixel coordinates or do you mean geographical coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

The GeoJSON format only supports the WGS84 CRS.

> The coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates is a
> geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic
> System 1984 (WGS 84) [WGS84] datum, with longitude and latitude units
> of decimal degrees.

Please see the [website](http://geojson.org/) for more information or read the specification [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946).

If you need to reproject GeoJSON, you could look at https://github.com/perliedman/reproject.